# Making clear text format in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, transparency, sublime-text-plugin, text-formatting, cleartext

I am using Sublime Text 3 editor. I changed background to transparence. But letters are being shown dim, not clear. That's why I want to change text (interface text also) for making clear text format. Sadly I couldn't do this. If someone can solve this matter please help me.

Thank you for attention!